How do I distinguish paste and input in terminals?
In the latest versions of terminals (gnome-terminal, mate-terminal, konsole, xfce4-terminal, xterm, etc), programs seem aware of whether some text is from paste or keyboard input. Specifically:

If I paste something into bash, the pasted text would be highlighted, and newlines don't trigger command execution.
If I paste something into vim, the text would be inserted into the cursor position, even if it wasn't in insert mode.

What is this feature called? How do I imitate this behavior in my own program? Could I temporarily disable this feature in these programs?
Related: Why is Terminal automatically executing my command after pasting text?

Also related (on a sister site): How can I protect myself from this kind of clipboard abuse?

Related: prevent multi-line paste in bash

This question is similar to: Paste has odd behavior in shell. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also https://www.invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm-paste64.html where that feature was first introduced in xterm

At least the IRC client irssi also has a a feature where it checks the time between subsequent characters, and if the input comes fast enough, treats it as one pasted block. (That feature appears to be older than bracketed paste, and it does have the advantage that it works without special support from the terminal, and doesn't cause extra control sequences if left on for a program that doesn't know about it. The downside of course being that lag in input may cause it to fail.)

As Stéphane Chazelas's comments says, this feature is called "bracketed paste".
And from the linked page, you could use this to enable this feature:
printf '\33[?2004h'

And when everything is done, do this to revert to the state without this feature:
printf '\33[?2004l'

The pasted data will be quoted using ^[[200~...^[[201~, where ^[ is the escape character \e.
Because the latest versions of terminals also automatically sanitize pasted data to change ESC (\33 aka \e aka ^[) to U+241B ␛, which I don't know if there is a way to disable, the pasted data won't contain ^[[201~, so it doesn't need unescaping.
